# Is it possible to archive / backup an exact copy of a drive and all its partitions to restore to later on?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, backup

So I have a computer that has one boot drive. it works fine, I can use it easily.

However, for my own purposes I wanted to run a completely different windows install on said system, and then later delete it and completely restore it to its original state with no flaws whatsoever.

The system in particular has its main drive encrypted with "bitlocker" (windows' weird drive security tool or something)

Honestly had no clue it was part of the drive, Im not looking to remove / bypass it. I cant undo the change since the old system had changes made to it that were permanent / unremovable.

I can easily just wipe the drive and make a new install, but I want to restore the computer to its original state later on, since there are certain things I simply cannot backup because of the permissions / original install's settings. Is that possible? (I basically just want to use the computer for other purposes for a few months, and then restore it after Im done with it)

I can access all the drives and info from disk management via booted USB drive, it shows the bitlocker encrypted partition, aswell as the traditional boot and recover partitions. I want to save all of this to a big drive, and then restore it later on.

Comment: Yes; numerous commercial (paid) software can create backup images of your drive.  However, disabling BitLocker protection will increase the number of options both free and paid that can then accomplish that job.  Questions seeking software recommendations are out of scope here at Super User, which is the reason, I am saying it's possible without making any specific recomendation.